# Can not produce a doughnut chart for any object I send to component using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, charts, chart.js

I'm using `ng-repeat` and sending two objects to the component.
Inside the component, I created a doughnut chart (Which should display the values of each object), but for some reason the second doughnut chart is produced on the first one from the first run of the `ng-repeat` (I even see the values of the 2 objects on this single doughnut). In the end only one doughnut appears on the screen.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <canvas class="doughnut-chart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
'use strict';

const appModule = angular.module('appModule');

appModule.component('appSeveritiesComponent', {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/severitiesComponent/severitiesComponent.html',
    controller: severitiesComponentController,
    bindings: {
        severities: '<'
    }
});

severitiesComponentController.$inject = ["$timeout"];

function severitiesComponentController($timeout) {
    var that = this;

    that.keys = function() {
        return Object.keys(that.severities);
    }

    $timeout(that.keys, 0); //wait dom is ready

    that.keys1 = function() {

        that.arr = [];
        for (var key in that.severities)
            that.arr.push(that.severities[key]);

        new Chart(document.getElementsByClassName("doughnut-chart"), {
            type: 'doughnut',
            animationEnabled: true,
            responsive: true,
            data: {
                labels: Object.keys(that.severities),
                labels: { display: false },
                datasets: [{
//                  label: "Population (millions)",
                    backgroundColor: ["rgb(213, 65, 65)", "rgb(243, 171, 16)", "rgb(65, 176, 213)"],
                    data: that.arr
                }]
            },
            options: {}
        });
    }

    $timeout(that.keys1, 0); //wait dom is ready

}
```

Comment: Can you show your full code or a working example? I don't see any AngularJS directives in the HTML you provided. It'd be easier to help if we could reproduce the issue.

Comment: edited my js (: